# My files doesn't include in jar file Java

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a code which create 2 txt files.It works.But when I package my application to .jar file, I can't find my txt files and my application can't read their.

```
 try {
    KeyGenerator  kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("saves/data.ttg"), cipher));
    oos.writeObject("" + CurrentMoney);
    fos = new FileOutputStream("saves/key.ttg");
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    DESedeKeySpec keyspec = (DESedeKeySpec) skf.getKeySpec(key, DESedeKeySpec.class);
    fos.write(keyspec.getKey());
    fos.close();
    oos.close();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What is the problem?

P.S I use Intellij IDEA

P.P.S It's JavaFX project(if it can make a difference)

Comment: Files will be added to the `.jar` only if they're on the build path of your application. Should your app create those files only once and then re-use them forever?

Comment: Yes,it's should create once.

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to package files in the jar and read them back at runtime, or are you trying to write the files at runtime (to the filesystem) and then later read those files back?

Comment: Trying to write files when prog runs and later read

Comment: maybe the working directory is different than what you expect when running it from the jar file. And you try to write to `saves/key.ttg`. If the `saves` directory is missing in the current working directory, it won't be created and thus the saving/reading fails.

Comment: Try at the beginning something like: `File dir = new File("saves"); if (!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdir(); }` to make sure the `saves` directory actually exists. Or adapt the file names not to use the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
I used Maven. https://maven.apache.org/
Easy packing to exe or jar.Hightly recomended:D